# is there any way to have admin privileges in non-admin accounts in xp

Tags: windows-xp

I mean, like in windows 7 that you can access the files of other users only if you provide a correct password. Is there any way that we could implement this kind of OS behavior in xp?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes - but it is not as easy for browsing files, it is meant for running applications in the context of another user.

For example, you can right click on a shortcut to an application such as `Notepad` and choose `Run as...`, then logon as the user you want.

[image]

Any shortcuts within this application, such as My Documents will run as that user and default to the correct location - So, if you just want to browse files quickly, you can do it via this.

I have tried, however, you cannot open up explorer in this method. You can however open up the `Command Prompt` if you are comfortable at using it.

I do not expect there to be a problem using third party file browsers when launched this way, but I cannot really recommend any - there are a few questions on here that should help you.

Also, whilst at the `Command Prompt`, you can launch any application under any user by typing the following:

```
RUNAS /user:<NAME> <PROGRAM>
```

For example, the following will launch `notepad` under the `wil` user.

```
RUNAS /user:wil notepad
```